# Formatting text when going through a file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm going through each line of a text file which stores a list of names and trying to format each name in the following way:

```
for name in open(r'C:\names.txt', 'r'):
    print('Name: ',name, 'Email: ',email)
```

This prints 'Name: Rita' and 'Email: test@text.com' on separate lines instead of the same line apart from the last line of the file which prints correctly. I've tried adding end="" after the print but this prints the Email before the Name as it's aligning the wrong lines such as 'Email: test@test.comName: Hannah'

How can I properly align each variable and print to the same line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for name in open(r'C:\names.txt', 'r'):
    print('Name: ', name.rstrip(), 'Email: ',email)
```

The issue is that, in python, the line that you read from a file includes the trailing newline character.  Printing `name` thus prints a newline character and hence starts a newline.  To avoid that, remove the trailing newline.  The method `rstrip()` is one way to do that.  It will also remove other trailing whitespace but that is usually a virtue, not a fault.